# A solution to a transcendental equation

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, transcendental-equations

I have a transcendental equation as follows:

$$ e^{ax} = b+ax $$

for some constants $a>0$ and $b>0$. Is there a known solution for $x$?

I tried on Wolfram and it gave a solution which depended on an inverse logarithm function. Was trying to at least get an upper bound for $x$ using Taylor series, but went in vain.

Thanks for any help regarding a solution or a suggestion or an upper bound to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $z=ax+b$.
$$e^{z-b}=e^{-b}e^z=ke^z=z$$
$$-k=-ze^{-z}$$
The RHS is of the form where we can apply the Lambert W function, the inverse of $xe^x$:
$$W(-k)=-z$$
Thus
$$x=-\frac{W(-e^{-b})+b}a$$

Comment: Yup, this is what Wolfram gave as a solution. Can we get something neater than the usage of $W$?

Comment: @Lohith-kumar No, Lambert W is not expressible in elementary functions.

Comment: Oh, then, is there any other closed form expression for the above mentioned equation?

Comment: @Lohith-kumar This is probably the simplest expression for it. Any specialised maths package will have the Lambert W as a library function however.